# Axios.get() inside a map function to get data for multiple objects returning promise object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have been having a problem with an axios fetch call inside of a returned object from a Array.map function. Whenever I return the response it returns a promise object to the array with the data I need but I can't seem to parse the promise object to get the data I need from it. When I console.log the response I get a regular object and not a promise.

I have tried using Promise.all , using redux-thunk for dispatching (but this dispatches a different action for every array item), JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, however I can't seem to get the async to run in the array

```
export const checkStreamerStatus = streamers => {
  return{
    type: CHECK_STREAMER_STATUS,
    payload: {
      streamers: streamers.map(streamer => ({
        ...streamer,
        status: getStatus(streamer)
      }))
    }
  }
}

const getStatus = streamer => {
  return axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${streamer.social.youtube}&type=video&eventType=live&key=[API KEY]`)
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => err)    
}
```

I expect the code to output an array of objects with the data from the fetch call as a new key in each object called "status", and then I expect to update my state in my reducer with the returned array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for approach

> but I can't seem to parse the promise object

the main idea is: Promise is not about parsing data. It's about awaiting till data comes.

It may be done with `async/await`(and using redux-thunk since we cannot just return action in synchronous way)

```
export const checkStreamerStatus = (streamers) => async (dispatch) {
  dispatch({
    type: CHECK_STREAMER_STATUS,
    payload: {
      streamers: streamers.map(streamer => ({
        ...streamer,
        status: await getStatus(streamer)
      }))
    }
  });
}
```

The imperfection is all the `getStatus` will be called sequentially. And any next request will wait till previous is responded. To make all requests run in parallel we need to create N requests and then await for all with `Promise.all`:

```
async function appendWithStatus(streamer) {
  return {
    ...streamer, 
    status: await getStatus(streamer);
  };
}

export const checkStreamerStatus = (streamers) => async (dispatch) => {
    const streamersWithStatus = await Promise.all(streamers.map(appendWithStatus));
    dispatch({
      type: CHECK_STREAMER_STATUS,
      payload: {
        streamers: streamersWithStatus,
      }
   });
}
```